# input NgDatePicker formatting the selected date Angular

Tags: angular

I have checked all other questions that are related to mine but couldn't find the proper one.

I am using NgDatePicker in an Agular project with pop-up calendar selection. As place holder getting today's date as a Date type and pipe it with

> 'EEEE, MMMM, d, y'

My HTML code

```
    <div class="input-group">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="{{todayDate | date : 'EEEE, MMMM, d, y'}}" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="dateCal" ngDatePicker #d="ngDatePicker" (ngModelChange)="changeDate()">
    </div>
```

changeDate() is just triggering other functions to get data from DB according to the new selected date but I couldn't pipe the new selected date. It shows always as: 2021-08-09.

What I have tried: `instead of [()] just used with [ngModel]="dateCal | date: 'EEEE, MMMM, d, y'"` and in the changeDate($event) tried to update dateCal but it's not changing the selected date format as I expected.

My .ts:

```
dateCal: any; 

changeDate() {
this.dateCal = new Date(this.dateCal.getYear, this.dateCal.getMonth, this.dateCal.getDay)
... other functions
}
```

when this function is triggered, dateCal will be also updated like above but on change, it's updated in ts but in the HTML not. I'm doing something very wrong but I couldn't find it.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Comment: can you share the code of html where you have used NgDatePicker

Comment: @KumailHussain it's there actually, you can see the code in the My HTML code section

Comment: you want to set a default date or change date but it is not showing you the updated or changed value?

Comment: when I select a date from the pop up calendar it show as 2021-09-08 format but I want to show it like Wednesday 19, September 2021

Comment: You can't do that using this library

Comment: Is there a way to do it with another library ?

Comment: you can check my answer and the link i provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done but in a complex way, so to format the date based on your own  custom formating , NgDatePicker datepickers use custom date adapter and formatter. The custom NgbDateAdapter lets you use your own model i.e. the structure of ngModel. The custom NgbDateParserFormatter lets you use your own formatter or parser i.e. the date format in input field.

Example

```
/**
 * This Service handles how the date is rendered and parsed from keyboard i.e. in the bound input field.
 */
@Injectable()
export class CustomDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
  readonly DELIMITER = '/';

  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct | null {
    if (value) {
      let date = value.split(this.DELIMITER);
      return {
        day: parseInt(date[0], 10),
        month: parseInt(date[1], 10),
        year: parseInt(date[2], 10),
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct | null): string {
   //this is where you can fromat the date
    const dates = new Date(
      date.day + this.DELIMITER + date.month + this.DELIMITER + date.year
    );
    return dates.toDateString();
  }
}
```

Please see the `format` date function I have added it as an example but you need to check and test the dates are passed properly

For your easiness, I have created stackblitz link to show how it will work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jurjnz